# django csrf token : CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: python, django, csrf

I don't use a django form, we only process it with API and respond to the result.
I want to handle it without using @csrf_exempt.
When using a form, I know that you are using a tag, but in this case, it is difficult to write a tag. I can't get rid of csrf so I need help.
When receiving a request as a post, "CSRF token missing or incorrect." Appears. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a stateless API (i.e. you don't use cookies) you can safely disable CSRF as follows:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

@csrf_exempt
def post(request):
    return 'page'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the csrf token check the [csrf doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/csrf/).

You can add the given code to a global js file and then reference it anywhere. I'm including the code here, but it is the same in the docs.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
```

And then to get the csrf token:

```
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
```

Here is the an example of how I use it in my fetch:

```
fetch('some_url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            some_key: some_var,
            ...
        })
    })
    .then(response => {
        jsonResponse = response.json();
        status_code = response.status;

        if(status_code != 200) {
            
            alert('error');
        } else {
            alert('success');
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```

But make sure the csrf token is available in your template by including the csrf template tag `{% csrf_token %}`